# Move Whatsapp media folder to SD card without rooting?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, storage

Hello Android experts,

The internal storage of a Xiaomi Redmi 7A (Android 9) is running low, so I wish to free up space by moving Whatsapp media storage to the SD card.
I moved the folder manually, but the big issue with that, that the data is going to be simply redownloaded again and the whole exercise would be futile. So ideally I need to set the media storage to SD card. But I am also open to other solutions to this problem.

The phone belongs to a child, that is why I wouldn't like to root it.

Answer (score 0):

Some apps are written to be able to use SdCard for storage,  Whatsapp is not one of them.

You can see this in `Settings>Apps>Whatsapp>Storage`  Apps that can work with SdCard have a `change` button here.

But in Whatsapp you can goto `3dotmenu>Settings>Storage and Data>Manage Storage` and then select a chat group and delete selected items from it.

- Teach your child to do that.  They can't keep everything forever. And they can't have unlimited storage.
- Or upgrade the phone.

Comment: Is there at least an option in whatsapp to download files (images &videos) manually to a selected location (ie on the SD) card? I could teach the child to do that and then delete the message.